# ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'

Tags: windows

I am an Ubuntu novice and am looking for some help from experts. I downloaded an Ubuntu app from Windows (I use Windows 10) because I wanted to download Siberian CMS, a free open-source app maker. I have successfully installed Apache2 and am stuck in the installation process for MariaDB and PHP. I have been following the steps in the link attached. Long story short, when I type "sudo mysql_secure_installation" i get "ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)". I have been stuck at this phase forever and am desperate for help!

https://websiteforstudents.com/install-siberian-cms-on-ubuntu-16-04-18-04-with-apache2-mariadb-and-php-7-2/

Answer (score 0):

I encountered that error while installing Nextcloud and wrote a small article on how I managed to [fix HY000 [2002]](https://pawelrychlicki.pl/Article/Details/65/fixing-sqlstatehy000-2002-in-the-nextcloudowncloud-with-the-mysqlmariadb-and-the-tlsssl-ubuntu-linux-1804-server). You can check it for details but I think it is worth to try these things first:

- Disable SSL for now - go to `/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf` and comment this out: `ssl=on`
- Ensure you can read and write to the socket: `sudo chmod 777 /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock`
- It may be, for some reason, that your socket is somewhere else. You can check where your server creates the socket in `/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf` file. Search for a line starting with `socket =`. If that's the case then change this line to point at `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock`

Don't forget to restart your mysql server after taking these steps with `sudo systemctl restart mysql`