# I am having issues with Mysql and a local CLI version of WordPress

Tags: mysql, windows-subsystem-for-linux

For anyone that's curious, it's error 2002. I've been looking at a lot of websites and a lot of them have been helpful, I was able to successfully uninstall all of the dependencies from Mysql, and, reinstall them. I have been able to change my password and it's really nice and it wokrs on its own, I am even able ot use the sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start command, but, beyond that, I get the error message ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (13), when in the folder I try to run this command with WP, I am having issues. I have looked primarily at [this website](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233915/error-2002-hy000-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-run) and other websites and have not really had luck with the solutions, with the ones that they used.

```
./wp-cli.phar config create --dbname=newwpdb --dbuser=root --dbpass=<password> --dbhost=localhost --dbprefix=mcwp_
```

[mysqld: Can't read dir of '/etc/mysql/conf.d/' (OS errno 2 - No such file or directory)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1251816/mysqld-cant-read-dir-of-etc-mysql-conf-d-os-errno-2-no-such-file-or-dir?newreg=b504177b26994644871a7cad14f9d3e6)

Comment: @Nmath- I am using Ubuntu 20.04, good catch. Microsoft has documentation on how to use Mysql with WSL2, https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/tutorials/wsl-database. I have tried using a different username other than root and it's still not working. I still get the same error message. 

I have installed the WP core CLI using this tutorial, and, I am trying to right now generate the PHP config file- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9E1lyVyh4xc.

Comment: Agree with @Nmath here - We need more details.  Also would recommend providing some formatting, paragraphs, bullets, or whatever you can do to make your question more readable.  It's *very* unclear at the moment.  I do think that WSL is fine for running local (as you say) services like this.  Production would be another thing entirely, but it's great for dev/test.  But to help you, we first need to be able to understand the question.  Thanks!

Comment: @JacobSiegel Please *edit* your question rather than replying in comments.  Show the commands *you* are using -- we're probably not going to go watch a YouTube video to figure it out.  Thanks!

Comment: NotTheDr01ds, I will also edit the question in addition to replying to the comments. I have been busy trying to figure out if I am on a wild-goose chase in the first place and I do not want to mislead people, so, I want to wait until I have come to a conclusion to change the question, and, answer it, possibly. 

@Nmath, isn't it weird? I looked at wordpress.org and even though Linux is essentially supported by WordPress, if you look at their forums, hardly any of their discussion is focused on getting Linux set up. You're basically on your own. (One more comment before I edit my post)...

Answer (score 1):

### The solution

OKAY! After struggling with this for the past several days, I have finally found a solution. I was looking in the wrong place. Wordpress.org pointed me in the direction of the CLI tool, while their website does not have a lot of data, their [github page for it, does](https://github.com/wp-cli/wp-cli). There are wrong directions out on the net, which may be correct for other Distros of linux, but, when you're using the chmod commands in particular, you should as a best practice, I think use the sudo command. I then had the issue of connecting to the database, someone else of course has dealt with that issue before and the issue was with the fact that [I needed to start mySQL services](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/290793/wp-cli-error-establishing-a-database-connection-in-localhost-mamp).

### How did I get it to work with WSL2?

It was simple really. First of all, I missed a big key command using chmod to move the wp-cli.phar into the bin folder, which, would convert it into an executable, and, you could call it using the letters WP much like the name itself.

Okay, not very simple. But, once I figured out that I had a later version of mySQL, I couldn't use a lot of the code that was online. You would be surprised of how many people use older code, and, they use things depending on the different situation. Basically, the reason that the socket was not working, was because I believe that I did not have the secure installation setup for mysql set up correctly. I had to add a series of special characters to get my passsword up to a 100 strength, no matter if I used 50 characters, even if it was completely random, the algorithm did not consider the password strong enough.

In the end, I don't think that a lot of the ningx files really mattered. The command line tool with WordPress comes with a very excellent server tool that makes up for it not having an .htrouter file. Bitnami does not work as well with WSL2, because, I do not know of an easy way to start up a local development server with Bitnami. However, there IS a very easy local development server to use here that is ready to use without a lot of additional extra stuff.

### At one point, I had to uninstall a lot of the other WordPress installations

I don't know if this is me or on WSL, but, I had many incorrect or faulty installations prior to this, and, one was overriding the other installations before. Also, I feel like Nginx doesn't work natively with Wordpress, but, the sudo wp server command works natively with WordPress, so, you don't need to use third party software in order to get it to run.

### How awesome is WordPress in the command line?

Even the local development server I think is miles above the regular installation process, if you can get your hands on it, I think it is worth the time and effort. @Nmath, I will adjst my question later on today, but, I thought I would share my solution. I am really happy that I was able to find out that this works, because, as others have suggested, if WSL is able to do stuff like this, this opens up doors for WSL to be for more of an every day use.